# News Section in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list, library, item-styles

I need to create a News section in my website home page (image, title, link for details page, summery). My questions are :

1. What can I use for News section (lists or library) to create it?
2. How can I make this component on my home page with itemstyle.xslt?

I tried to make it but I can't make a link for details page so I think there is mistake in my way.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a list or a pages library on a publishing site. The publishing feature is only available with the Enterprise license.
2. You can build a list view web part, a data view web part (DVWP) or a content by query web part (CQWP).  DVWP can easily be styled in SharePoint Designer. CQWP styling requires changes to some core XSLT files, like itemstyle.xslt in the Style Library. Best practice is to make copies of these files and work on the copies. The benefit of a CQWP is that it will honour audience targeting fields, so you can target news for specific groups (departments, offices, projects).  There are lots of tutorials on the web for both DVWP and CQWP.
3. With a DVWP or a CQWP you can show the title (or any other field) as a link to the list item or page.